# Touchpad Problems with Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: touchpad

There is a Problem with my Notebook "Terra 360-11" with Ubuntu 16.04.1:

Touchpad ELAN SA461D-2000 does not work.

Can You help me?

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Laser Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIS0817:00 0457:1134                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera                            id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: I am afraid this touchpad is not supported yet.

Comment: o.k., thank you. I will waiting up it is supported. To become a good wine you have to wait too....